# How do I use symbols to access a JSON response with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash, https

I am using HTTPparty gem to send request in my rails application. Here is an example:

```
order = HTTParty.get("https://sandbox.moip.com.br/v2/payments/#{o.payment_id}",
                headers: {"Authorization" => "Basic #{encode_auth_token}"})

order_status = JSON.parse(order.body)
```

The variable order receives a json as response. I've managed to retrieve the information that I need, but i wanted to use symbols, instead of string to access the json data.

Is there any way to access my json data using symbols? For example:

```
order_status[:link]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spoiler alert: **best option is #3**

---

**Option 1:** you can call [`.with_indifferent_access`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/with_indifferent_access) on the Hash to be able to access the values by using either `'link'` or `:link`:

```
{'a' => 1}[:a]
# => nil
{'a' => 1}.with_indifferent_access[:a]
# => 1
{'a' => 1}.with_indifferent_access['a']
# => 1
```

**Option 2:** call [`.symbolize_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys) (or [`.deep_symbolize_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/deep_symbolize_keys) if you want to symbolize the nested keys too) on the hash to convert all keys to symbols:

```
hash = { 'name' => 'Rob', 'address' => { 'postal_code' => '92210' } }
hash.symbolize_keys
# => {:name=>"Rob", :address=>{'postal_code'=>'92210'}}
hash.deep_symbolize_keys
# => {:name=>"Rob", :address=>{:postal_code=>'92210'}}
```

**Option 3:** parse the JSON with the `symbolize_names` option set to `true`

```
JSON.parse(string, symbolize_names: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching deeper, I've found a more concise way to solve this using the .symbolize_keys!, for example:

```
order_status = JSON.parse(order.body).symbolize_keys![:status]
```

For more reference: https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys%21

> Destructively convert all keys to symbols, as long as they respond to to_sym. Same as symbolize_keys, but modifies self.

Comment: Actually, `JSON.parse` accepts an option argument `symbolize_names: true`

Comment: It has the same effect to use this argument, as symbolize_keys! ?

Comment: I see haha. Thanks for the tip. I will try to refactor that.

Comment: It's almost the same effect, but not quite....try both using `"{\"hello\":\"there\",\"names\":[{\"name\":\"First\"},{\"name\":\"Second\"}]}"`...using `JSON.parse(string, symbolize_keys: true)`, the `"name"` keys are symbols...using `Hash#symbolize_keys` only the `"hello"`and `"names"` key is a symbol...but there's also [`Hash#deep_symbolize_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) that will convert the `"name"` keys.

Comment: so... `symbolize_keys` only do its job at the top level keys (not the nested ones), but `with_indifferent_access` does it for the nested keys (ex: `{ 'a' => { 'b' => 3 } }.with_indifferent_access[:a][:b]` return `3`). Expect the unexpected!!